# How to compare all values of user input to find if 2 values are identical

Tags: c++

I was trying to do a function where it would ask the user for 6 numbers to enter and compare all the values (they were put in an array) to find if there is 2 of the same values. The function I did always returns true.

I figured that if tbl[0] = 0 and it does tbl[0] == tbl[0] well it's always going to return true. The thing is this was for an exam and I cannot change how it is initialized, so I guess my method is simply not the right one.

```
#include <iostream>

int tbl[6] = { 0 }

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "What's the number #" << i + 1 << "? ";
            std::cin >> tbl[i];
        }

bool contientDoublons(int tbl[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // increase the i after comparing j all 6 times
                                // to compare every cell with every other one
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (tbl[i] == tbl[j])
            {
                return true; // returns true if 2 identical values are found
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is passed as `tbl`? Be kind to post a [mcve].

Comment: Your code looks fine. The problem is in the part of your code you didn't show. [Edit] and post a [mcve].

Comment: Counting would be much simpler, and faster. The fact that `contientDoublons()` is not passed an array size is problematic.

Comment: What size table do you send to your function? 5, 6 or another size?

Comment: Why seven? Looks like it should be a six element array to me.

Comment: @sweenish Yeah, I was off by one there.

Comment: It does [not always](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a2211dfe0d666a4) return `true`. You have probably been so certain that it's an indexing issue that you didn't think to look elsewhere for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current method *should* work, but it's terribly inefficient and more error-prone. As noted in comments, the issue isn't necesasrily in what you've shown. If I had to guess, it's an off-by-one error. Typically when passing C-arrays to functions, you also pass the size of the array as an additional parameter.

But let's take a moment to think about the problem. You need to find out if a given array has duplicates or not. It runs in O(n^2) time, which means that as the size of your input grows, the time it will take your program to run grows exponentially. And that shoud make intuitive sense, given the nested for loops.

Let's consider an alternate approach. We will "count" the elements as we come across them, using a `std::unordered_set`. This container can only contain *unique* values. So, as we look through the table, if an element is in the set, we can immediately know we're looking a duplicate and return true. If not, we add it to the set since it's the first time we've seen that value.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

bool contientDoublon(int const (&tbl)[5]) {
  std::unordered_set<int> elements;
  for (auto const &i : tbl) {
    if (auto [itr, succeeded] = elements.insert(i); !succeeded) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << "Expect false: " << contientDoublon({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) << '\n'
            << "Expect true: " << contientDoublon({1, 1, 2, 3, 4}) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Expect false: false
Expect true: true
```

As we can see from looking at the code, I only make a single pass through the table (runtime is O(n)) at most, and only look at each element once.

Comment: Complexity doesn't necessary mean faster BTW. Especially when `N` is small. (OP hard-code size to 6...)

Comment: You might do a single lookup by element by checking result of `insert` instead of `find`.

Comment: Fair point. I suppose I don't highlight it as much, but I find the counting solution to also be less error-prone.

Comment: @Jarod42 I like that.

Comment: `std::/*unordered_*/set{v.begin(), v.end()}.size() == v.size();` for simplicity ;-)

Comment: That would require iterating the entire input. My method (now edited to rely on `insert()` alone) can return at the first found duplicate.

Comment: Yes, different code, different trade-off. complexity/simplicity/speed/... ;-)